# Dynamically add fields in Dynamic Form Array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a form which has a form array like

```
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      arr: this.fb.array([this.createItem()])
    })

I can dynamically add fields to the array as

    createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      pay: [''],
      type: []
    })
  

    addItem() {
    this.arr = this.myForm.get('arr') as FormArray;
    this.arr.push(this.createItem());}

the type control is a dropdown with values as 


    
  types = [
    { id: 10, name: 'A' },
    { id: 20, name: 'B' },
    { id: 30, name: 'C' },
  ];
```

My Question is if the user selects Type 'A' for a group I want to add two more fields 'phone' and 'address' and for 'B' and 'C', I want the particular group to not add fields.

For Example if user selects 'A' for first entry of form Array I will add controls
'phone' and 'address' to the 'this.fb.group' and if user changes it to 'B' or 'C' for
that row in array I will remove these two fields.

I would like to subscribe to the type formcontrol check type and add controls but how to
do it?
The stackblitz is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-array-fmyxvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to `type` FormControl `valueChanges` and based on its value, add or remove FormControls using `addControl` and `removeControl` methods.

Below is the code snippet that might help you get going:

```ts
    createItem() {
      const newFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        name: [''],
        pay: [''],
        type: [],
      });
      newFormGroup.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {  // should be unsubscribed later to avoid memory leaks
        if (value == 10) {  // 10 is the id for A
          this.addAdditionalControls(newFormGroup);
        } else {
          this.removeAdditionalControls(newFormGroup);
        }
      });
      return newFormGroup;
    }
    
    addAdditionalControls(formGroup: FormGroup) {;
      formGroup.addControl('phone', new FormControl(''));
      formGroup.addControl('address', new FormControl(''));
    }
    
    removeAdditionalControls(formGroup: FormGroup) {
      if (formGroup.get('phone') && formGroup.get('address')) {
        formGroup.removeControl('phone');
        formGroup.removeControl('address');
      }
}
```

In `html` file you can conditionally display the dynamic controls:

```html
    <select placeholder="Type" formControlName="type">
      <option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.id">
        {{ type.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <ng-container *ngIf="a.get('phone')">
      <br /><br />
      <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" formControlName="phone" />
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="a.get('address')">
      <br /><br />
      <label for="address">address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="address" formControlName="address" />
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your FormArray should be an FormArray of FormGroups with the same "structur", only not show the inputs if the type is not "A". For this only need use in the .html

```
*ngIf="myForm.get('arr.'+i+'.type').value!='A'
```

-where "i" is the index you iterate the formArray-. If you need a Validator, use a custom validator over the group

```
createItem() {
    return this.fb.group(
      {
        name: [''],
        pay: [''],
        type: [],
      },
      { validator: this.requiredIfType() }
    );
  }
  requiredIfType() {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const group = control as FormGroup;
      if (control.get('type').value != 10) return null;
      let error = null;
      if (!control.get('name').value) error = { nameRequired: true };
      if (!control.get('pay').value) error = { ...error, payRequired: true };

      return error;
    };
  }
```

and you can use

```
    <div class="error" *ngIf="myForm.get('arr.' + i + '.name').touched &&
                  myForm.get('arr.' + i).errors?.nameRequired">
      Name required
    </div>

    <div class="error" *ngIf="myForm.get('arr.' + i + '.pay').touched &&
                  myForm.get('arr.' + i).errors?.payRequired">
      Payment required
    </div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-array-ypze21?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)